# Does TURN Server (WebRTC) eliminate redundant uploads (like SFU)?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, p2p, turn, ice

The problem with p2p apps is the amount of Uploads, since most connections are asymmetrical (weak upload, strong upload).

If you're connected to 10 Peers you have to upload your own video stream 10 times, which quickly falls apart.

SFU (selecting forwarding units) solve this by routing your single upload to all peers.

Does a TURN server do the same? Technically it could, since it's already acting as a relay, but my fear is that it tries to emulate the underlying p2p protocol to closely and hence Uploads are still redundant?

Answer (score 1):

No. TURN servers do not decrypt, SFUs need to do that (and a couple of things that require more logic). They're different components, solving different problems.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default TURN server doesn't do it.

You can take some more complicated webrtc servers like flussonic for example (maybe wowza) and get star topology with them.